# how to use php tidy in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-5, tidy

I have a method in laravel project that check the mailbox and get the message body
and store it in a database the problem is I get the result like this

```
<div>check<br></div>
  <div> <br></div>
  <blockquote class="protonmail_quote" type="cite">
    <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;<br></td>
          <td>
            <div><p></p>
```

is there a way to autocomplete HTML before storing it a database

Comment: You will need a function to process the html before it goes into the DB to complete the html. Issue is, do you want to complete just the tags that are missing? Or complete the html with body tag, head tag and everything else missing that you would normally see on an html page?

Comment: found solution with htmlawed tools